# Inconsistent Product URL

Tags: magento2, product, url, url-rewrite, product-urls

I'm facing an issue in Magento 2.2.0 and Unero Theme 1.3.2 where there are products that have an URL like:

**https://example.com/catalog/product/view/id/440/s/product-url-key/57/**

and the others are:

**https://example.com/product-url-key.html**

I'm checking the condition of SEO setting in the catalog's configuration, but I think it's already correct in the store view level setting.

[image: SEO Store View Configuration]

And this is the SEO settings in the catalog -> product itself 
[image: SEO Product Settings]

I'm currently at the beginning state of developing and learn Magento Programming. Do it need code modification in core / theme? Or there are something wrong with the configuration?

Expected result are the second one where there is .html in the product's URL

Thanks.

Comment: In admin products section you selected catalog,search??

Comment: Thank you for your edit suggestion. Yes, the visibility is catalog, search. Is this affecting the URL's generation?

Comment: I am found some days ago same problem my site and i have changed the visibility. And my issue is solved.

Comment: it is possible that some products in the past didn't generate, to regenerate all use https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls (this can update product urls as well  as catalog).  check that new products are created correctly .  I had this issue and used a SQL script to check for enabled and visible products correctly appearing in the url_rewites table

Comment: @Barry does it run in the PHP 7.1 and Magento 2.2.0 ? I've seen the release version  just added PHP 7.3 on composer require list. Thank you anyway for your suggestion!

Comment: @MohitPatel No, it doesn't give any effect after I try.

Comment: @MBK1People sorry I don't know, I used magento 2.3 the php version should be fine (if not then you'll  need to make minor changes to get working). I would guess it would again be only minor changes again for magento 2.2.0.  Obviously try in a test site first and see.

Comment: This one works : https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites @Barry for Magento 2.2 runs in PHP 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a solution by a fellow developer that this one is working with PHP 7.1 and Magento 2.2.0 : https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites